# Can valgrind output an execution trace in VEX IR?

Tags: debugging, valgrind, trace

I am new to valgrind. My understanding is that valgrind is similar to Intel PIN, i.e., it is a binary instrumentation tool.

Is it possible to make valgrind output a full execution trace, i.e. a long list of all executed instructions (translated to vex IR)? It seems basic to me but I could not find any info about how to do this.

The closest I could find was the possible gdb integration described [here](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver).
Using gdb to generate the trace seems to be not a good approach as valgrind must have the IR instructions anyway when they are executed.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

valgrind has various tracing options of the VEX IR.

See   valgrind --help-debug

Maybe also the -tool=lackey  might be useful.